# How to suppress compilation output when using ports in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd

Is it possible to configure the FreeBSD ports system to suppress the compilation output (like brew does in OS X)? The output is mostly useless for me and can be a waste of bandwidth (when working over ssh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply send the output somewhere other than your terminal.

If you're using Bourne-family shells:

```
# make config
# make install >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you're using a C-shell variant:

```
# make config
# make install >&/dev/null
```

You may want to route the output to a real file instead of `/dev/null` in case something goes wrong and you need to review the output.

---

Note that you need to run `make config` separately for any port that requires configuration (so the little menu/dialog screen shows up).

Answer (score 0):

if you use portmaster for your ports, it has a -H flag that hides most of the extra output and puts it in a log file.